# Client Timberline Office Integration from a .NET Web Application

Tags: asp.net, odbc, pervasive

I have an ASP.NET application where I need to push data from the ASP.NET application into the client's Timberline Office database at the users request.  I need to do this by connecting to the client's Pervasive ODBC Driver to insert data into the Timberline data structures.

I would like to build a component (ActiveX, or something like that) that would work in IE at a minimum, and also the Firefox and Chrome browsers if possible.  I would like to build this component using VB.NET and Visual Studio 2008 if possible.

Can anyone provide any resources (web sites, code examples) to help me with this?

Thanks